# Best practice to support portrait and landscape interface orientations in a iPad iOS 4.3

Tags: ipad, ios4, uiviewcontroller, orientation, nib

In the document,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW6

they have used **performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:** and **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:** which are available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Is there any smart way to use multiple nibs for different ipad interface orientations in iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a PortraitViewController and a LandscapeViewController.

You will need the following:

```
@interface PortraitViewController : UIViewController {
    BOOL isShowingLandscapeView;
    LandscapeViewController *landscapeViewController;
}

@implementation PortraitViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    landscapeMainViewController = [[LandscapeMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandscapeMainViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice]  endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [landscapeMainViewController release]; landscapeMainViewController = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:landscapeMainViewController animated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end


@interface LandscapeViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation LandscapeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil  bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

@end
```

Credits: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/alternativeviews-in-iphone/